# How to increase the semantic version number?

Tags: c#, .net, versioning, semantics, semantic-versioning

I use `semver spec 2.0`.
What should be the version number increments when
the current version `2.0.0-beta.1` is has already been distributed.
Now, a bug is fixed.
If version `2.0.1-beta.1` or `2.0.0-beta.2` be better?

Comment: is the bug backwards compatible?

Comment: Ok, it's backwards compatible

Answer (score 1):

If the bug fix is backwards compatible you should increment the PATCH version (e.g. 2.0.0-beta.1->2.0.1-beta.1).  If the bug fix is not backwards compatible with the last minor/major version then you should increment the MINOR or MAJOR version, depending on what isn't backwards compatible.  Which, I would assume, mean a whole new beta.  E.g. 2.0.1-beta.1->2.1.0-beta.1 or 2.0.1-beta.1->3.0.0-beta.1.

If it's a non-backward bug fix from a the previous *beta*, then it's really up do you to decide what level of support you want in a beta.

Comment: You mean, the beta level is freeze and only the major, minor and patch  version is increment?
And when should i increment the beta.1 to beta.2?

Comment: With semver there's a lot of leeway with beta. You can roughly follow the MAJOR/MINOR rules and assume that if you make a breaking change to a beta 1 in a new build that it's just beta 2 because you don't really need to support beta 2. To look at it much more deeply means you'd need another layer of M/P versioning (e.g. M1.m1.p.b.M2.m2.)  Generally, when you release a beta you're not making an semantic guarantees about backward compatibility between different beta versions of the same minor version.  e.g. if you introduce a new feature in beta 1 and break it in b1, you can just call it b2.